# Where is the directory of user icon on Monterey

Tags: user-account, monterey

I used to be able to access the directory of the default Apple User Icons, e.g. the tennis ball or the violin via the Library.
Now with the upgrade to Monterey I cannot find that directory anymore, also cannot find any .tif files in the Library sub-directories at all, if I can trust the search function.

Due to some MGMT software we cannot edit our user profile photos which is frustrating, and the last "hack" was to swap the default icon image with a preferred one.

Thanks in advance,
someone who does not identify as "violin"

Comment: It's likely that they'll be PNG, not TIFF, and inside /System, not /Library.

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion. on my previous OS they were TIF apparently